# Gridview with linqdatasource refreshing view?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, linqdatasource

I've a gridview bound to linqdatasource1 and a details bound to linqdatasource2 (for searching).

When I update the data on detailsview, my gridview is not updating. I've tried handling various gridview events and databinding the gridview in code but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please add some code to your question, dont expect people to guess it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a .DataBind on the gridview as you manipulate data in the detailview

Comment: @Citronas I'm going to give you credit though because for some reason now it is working and I've not changed any of my code but I wouldn't ask something so basic as that. Thanks though for trying.